# Why is Java Ignoring My serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

I've got a class which defines `public static final Long serialVersionUID = 123L;`.

When I actually serialize it or even if I run it through Java's `serialver.exe` it comes back with an arbitrary auto-generated serialVersionUID dependent on the method signatures at compilation time or however Java normally derives those.

Why is Java ignoring my explicitly specified `serialVersionUID` and how can I get it to stop?

**Edit**: Here's a minimal example which also demonstrates the above behavior.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demonstration</groupId>
    <artifactId>serialization</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

src/main/java/demonstration/serialization/Example.java:

```
package demonstration.serialization;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Example implements Serializable {
        private static final Long serialVersionUID = 123L;
}
```

Do an `mvn clean package` to create the output jar, then run the following command (modified as appropriate for your JDK):

```
"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.1.7-openj9\bin\serialver.exe" -classpath target/serialization-1.0.jar demonstration.serialization.Example
```

I get back:

```
demonstration.serialization.Example:    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8528929994176475972L;
```

That's not the value of 123 that I specified. And in my slightly more complex example, the ObjectOuputStreams and ObjectInputStreams confirm that my specified values are being ignored.

Comment: Well. Your observation seems to be wrong. A [mcve] please!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The observation appears true even for a very minimal example project. Edited into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. `Long` is not the same as `long`; be sure when specifying a serialVersionUID that it matches the exact form:

private static final **long** serialVersionUID = [value]L;